# API call parameter undefined on initial login

Tags: .net, angular, rxjs, powerbi

I'm working on a full-stack application using Angular and .NET where I have embedded a Power BI report. In this application, clients have the ability to save bookmarks for a specific page. The bookmarks are saved in the back end and retrieved through a service in the front end. This functionality works perfectly fine everywhere, except during the initial login of the website.

The Issue:
Upon the initial login, the parameter being sent to the API call (`getUserBookmarks()`) is undefined. The parameter only gets populated after a page reload or navigation. This leads to a failed API call because of the undefined parameter. Subsequent reloads work as expected.

Code Snippets:
Here is how I'm calling the service:

```
private GetUserBookMarks() {
    this.getUserBookmarksObservable = this.httpService.getUserBookmarks(this.GetBookMarkRequest()).subscribe(x => {
      this.userBookMarkList = x;
    });
}
```

Here is my constructor

```
constructor(
    private store: Store,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    public httpService: HttpService,
    public authService: AuthService,
    public sharedService: SharedService,) {
    UserAccessStore.subscribe((state) => {
      const { userAcceessData } = state;
      this.userAcceessData = userAcceessData;
      if (this.userAcceessData && (this.userAcceessData.userType === "ClientAdmin" || this.userAcceessData.userType === "ClientUser")) {
        this.selectedClientId = this.configService.clientId;
        this.displayClientName = "";
      }
      this.menuSubscription$ = MenuStore.subscribe((state) => {
        const { menuList } = state;
        this.menuList = menuList;
        if (this.selectedClientId) {
          this.displayDefaultReport();
        }
      });
      this.selectSubscription$ = SelectedReportStore.subscribe((state) => {
        this.newSelectedReport = state.selectedReport;
        if (this.newSelectedReport && this.selectedClientId) {
          this.embedReport(state.selectedReport!);
          this.GetUserBookMarks();
        }
      });
      this.authService.user$.subscribe(res => {
        this.userName = res?.email!;
        this.authName = res?.name!;
      })
    });
  }
```

Here is my service

```
getUserBookmarks(userBookmarksGetRequest: UserBookmarksGetRequest): Observable<UserBookmarkResponse[]> {
    let queryParams = new HttpParams();
    queryParams = queryParams
      .append("ClientId", userBookmarksGetRequest.clientId)
      .append("UserName", userBookmarksGetRequest.userName)
      .append("UserEmail", userBookmarksGetRequest.userEmail)
      .append("ReportName", userBookmarksGetRequest.reportName)
      .append("PowerBIReportId", userBookmarksGetRequest.powerBIReportId);

    return this.httpClient.get<UserBookmarkResponse[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/api/v1/report/userbookmark`, { params: queryParams });
}
```

What I've tried:
Checked the order of service calls.
Verified if the problem lies in the `ngOnInit(`) lifecycle hook.
Used RxJS's `combineLatest` to manage multiple observables.
None of these approaches have resolved the issue.

I'd appreciate any help or suggestions to fix this issue.

Feel free to add or remove any information you see fit, and good luck getting your issue solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my SelectedReportStore was a regular subject. This meant it wasnt being called until I explicitly called .next(). I changed the subject to a BehaviorSubject and found succcess.

Answer (score 0):

you have to wait for the observables to emitte This ensures that you have all the necessary data before proceeding.

```
constructor(
  // ... other dependencies
) {
  combineLatest([
    this.authService.user$,
    UserAccessStore,
    MenuStore,
    SelectedReportStore
  ]).subscribe(([user, userAccess, menu, selectedReport]) => {
    this.userName = user?.email!;
    this.authName = user?.name!;
    this.userAcceessData = userAccess.userAcceessData;

    // ... other logic

    if (this.newSelectedReport && this.selectedClientId) {
      this.embedReport(this.newSelectedReport!);
      this.GetUserBookMarks();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I have tried that and the observables never emit. I added a console log right after the subscribe and it never gets called. The page never proceeds to perform its desired functionality upon login. Any suggestions?

Comment: check your authService try to get one by one see first if you get a user. return  this.authService.user$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(user => {
      console.log(user)
    });

Comment: So I went and tried each one and it looks like they all work as expected expect SelectedReportStore. That never runs unless I refresh the page.